# Android change onCreateViewHolder() returning viewHolder from custom calback

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to return viewHolder in recyclerview onCreateViewHolder() asynchronously.

At start the `viewHolder` should be like it is in the first line (and it works until now) but once my callback is called later on, `viewHolder` should be as it is set inside my callback. Unfortunatelly this never happens. Here is the code:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    viewHolder = new VHStart(LayoutInflater.from(fragment.requireContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_note_loading,parent,false));
    if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_ONE) {
        MyView myView = new MyView(parent.getContext(), this);
        myView.inflate(new OnFinishedInflated() {
            @Override
            public void onFinished(View view) {
                viewHolder = new VHSingleElement(view);
            }
        });
    } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_TWO) {
        // will add this later
    } else
        throw new RuntimeException("No such view type");

    return viewHolder;
}
```

How to solve that?

Comment: What is even the point of the callback?

Comment: you do not need inflate .. just return `viewHolder = new VHSingleElement(myView)`

Comment: Actually I need to have this callback because behind the scenes I use AsyncLayoutInflater so I need to wait until its done.

Comment: I would actually try to avoid such solutions because recycler view layout manager really does need view to be laid out (and bound) immediately to prevent inconsistencies and expensive layout measurement passes. If your items are so heavy you need async inflater maybe you have to rethink your layout structure in general.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of `AsyncLayoutManager` is that it doesn't block UI thread - so when you tell `mView` to `inflate` it immediately goes to next instruction(`return viewHolder`) because the inflation goes to background thread.

You can't retroactively change it what the function returned.

You want to set up each `ViewHolder` type to have initial state - basically what your `VHStart` is currently and have internal transition to it's final form.

The most basic version of this pattern is `ProgressBar` that you hide/remove once content is loaded.

```
class AsyncVH : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    private var isInflated: Boolean = false
    private var item: Item? = null
    private var view: View
    

    AsyncVH(view: View) {
        ViewGroup itemParent = (ViewGroup) view
        AsyncLayoutInflater(view.context).inflate(new OnFinishedInflated() {
            @Override
            public void onFinished(View asyncView) {
                // Hide/remove if you have initial progress view from view
                itemParent.clearAll() // view.findViewById(R.id.progress).setVisibility(View.GONE)
                itemParent.addView(asyncView)
                isInflated = true
                bind()
            }
        });
    }

    void bind(item: Item) {
        this.item = item
        if(isInflated) {
            bind()
        }
    }

    private void bind() { 
        if (isInflated && item != null) {
            // bind
        }
    }
}
```